# Unrelated actions, as in 'Do you walk to school or eat tofu?'

Tags: single-word-requests, parts-of-speech, metaphors

I'm looking for a word that describes the choice between two unrelated actions.
Example "do you walk to school or eat tofu?"

The word sounds like  non-secular or noncircular.

Comment: Though the word describing the second, unrelated statement has been given (though 'non-sequitur' has appeared many times on ELU), the whole sentence is an incongruity. Assuming that it is not licensed by previous context: "Shoe and sandwich thieves operate on the lane between your house and St Disgustine's...."

Comment: It could also be considered a [false dilemma, false dichotomy, or false binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma) if you're assuming everyone must either walk to school or eat tofu.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the word you’re looking for is *non sequitur*.

From Vocabulary.com:

> A non sequitur is a conclusion or reply that doesn't follow logically from the previous statement.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, no problem.

Comment: This may well be the phrase that the OP had heard and was trying to recall, but it does not mean 'the choice between two unrelated actions'.

Answer (score 0):

Intonation will decide. The way the question is pronounced depends on whether it's a yes/no question with two or more parts but only one answer, as in

- *Do you use tobacco, caffeine, or alcohol?*
  {to which the answer is *yes* if you use one or more of them, and *no* if you use none)

as opposed to a "choose one" question, which requires an answer referring to one of the parts, as in

- *Do you use sugar, cream, or honey?*
  (which requires an answer choosing one or more, or else an answer choosing none)

Note that the two questions have different intonations. If you say either aloud, its intonation contour tells you what kind of question it is. And if you swap the intonation contours, you get a joke.